# How can I free up n bytes of memory in C?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, free

I wanted to create a generic Linked List in C. Following is the structure of the node:

```
typedef struct node {
    void *value;
    int size;        // n bytes
    ind index;       // index of the node
    struct node *next;
} Node;
```

And my delete_node function is as following. The search function sends a pointer to the Node I want to delete.

```
Node *search_list(Node *list, void *data, int n_bytes);
int delete_node(Node *list, Node *to_be_deleted);       // returns 1 on success
```

Inside the `delete_node` function I want to free up the memory pointed by `void *value` and then free up the memory allocated for the `Node` itself.

```
free(to_be_deleted->value);      // Would this work??
free(to_be_deleted);
```

Since it is `void` pointer we don't know that how many bytes the object it is pointing to has occupied. How can we free up the memory for that?
Sorry if it is a stupid questions?

Comment: You very seldom count bits in C; bytes — yes, frequently, but bits — not often.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh yes, bad naming. I changed it nbytes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
free(to_be_deleted->value);      // Would this work??
```

Straight forward answer , `Yes this will work.`

simple thing :

see the definitions of `free()` and `malloc()`

`void free(void *)  // free takes void* as argument so it will work`

`void* malloc(sizeof(type))`

In `malloc`we have to pass the`size` that how many bytes we want to allocate.

but in `free` just pass the pointer and whatever bytes allocated to that pointer on heap storage it will be freed

Answer (score 3):

The memory allocator keeps track of how large memory allocations are on its own -- there's no need to tell `free()` how much memory to free.

As such, you should be able to just get rid of `size` and `n_bits`.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, what you wrote should work. The reason is that malloc (which is a library call) creates metadata that is used to determine which parts of memory are free and which ones are taken. When you call free(), you are actually only modifying this metadata such that subsequent calls to malloc know that this memory can be re-used (note that most implementations will not zero the existing data).